# Cpanel - Startup Script

Tags: cpanel, centos7, whm

How can one go about getting a java command when they reboot their server using Cpanel or WHM?  I have a spring boot application running (starting it using java -jar jarname.jar.  When I restart Cpanel I have to run the script manually.  How Can I make it so the command will automatically run when Cpanel or Centos7 restart?  I installed java as the root so I dont know if that means I have to run it as a Centos7 script instead of a Cpanel script of some sort.

The error I am currently getting using a centos7 systemctl service:

```
blah.service - Startsspring boot
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/blah.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2018-04-27 19:19:47 EDT; 2s ago
Process: 3642 ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash /usr/bin/blah.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 3642 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 27 19:19:47 server systemd[1]: Started Starts spring boot.
Apr 27 19:19:47 server systemd[1]: Starting Starts spring boot...
```

Thats all the help i get says it starts but the service never starts my jar it says inactive :(

startups script:

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts spring boot
After=network.target
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash /usr/bin/blah.sh
Type=simple
User=root
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

the .sh file **(works fine if i run it command line)**

```
/usr/bin/nohup /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-0.b14.el7_4.x86_64/jre/bin/java -jar /home/domain/public_html/jarname.jar &
```

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here.  I just did the java command in the systemd service not in a shell script.

https://techdev.io/en/developer-blog/jvm-applications-as-a-service-with-systemd